# why script tag with javascript doesn't work in ionic project?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing a quiz part of my project based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvk1pFNqXaw) tutorial. However, I have tried placing the script tags containing javascript files just before closing the body tag, but it doesn't read the javascript files at all. I have also tried running javascript code inside the script tags but same result. It works fine when i run the code outside the ionic project by creating a separate javascript project. 
Do i have to specify somewhere that i'm using .js files in the project instead of .ts? How should i run a javascript code inside my ionic project?
Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<ion-header>
  
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Quiz</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<body>
<div class="grid">
    <div id="quiz">
        <p id="progress"><b>Question</b></p>
        <p id="question"></p>
        <div class="answers">
          <input type="radio" id="r0"><span id="q0"></span><br/><br/>
          <input type="radio" id="r1"><span id="q1"></span><br/><br/>
          <input type="radio" id="r2"><span id="q2"></span><br/><br/>
          <input type="radio" id="r3"><span id="q3"></span><br/><br/>
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
<script src="quiz_controller.js"></script>
<script src="question.js"></script>
<script src="quiz_app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know Ionic, perhaps it is using `'body'` as selector for the root component, which purges the content of the `<body>` tag when Angular is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for responding, that make sense, so how would you do this in angularjs?

Comment: I guess you have no influence what selector Ionic uses for for the root component. What about just adding `async`  or `defer` to the script tag and adding it to the `<head>` instead of the `<body>`? - or wait for a better answer, I really don't know anything about Ionic, except that it's somehow based on Angular2.

Comment: Where is this file at? `www>index.html` or inside `app>page`?

Comment: it's in src>pages

Comment: So, did you get an answer? @Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference a JavaScript file, I had to make sure the .js file is in the "www" folder and call it from the .ts file like this...

```
declare function require(name: string);
var quiz = require('../../../www/questions');
```